# How to create xml file in Eclipse-Kepler

Tags: xml, eclipse-kepler

Can anybody tell me how to create an xml file in Eclipse ?.

Project right click->new->other.. does not shows an xml wizard.

New->file and renaming it as filename.xml does not give the xml design page.

I am using Eclipse -Kepler 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> New -> File and name it yourname.xml

Comment: Project right click->new->other.. does not shows an xml wizard.

New->file and renaming it as filename.xml does not give the xml design page.

Comment: @ kphil hi ,There is not an xml editor come along with Eclipse Kepler. So i need to install it from the Eclipse MarketPlace.Thank you.

Comment: Kepler is a simultaneous release version, not a definitive single download. There are different packages with different contents, many of which *do* contain the XML Editor.